# scroll page in PDFTron

Tags: reactjs, pdftron

I am trying to scroll to a text position by onClick event by quads that are stored in the database.

I can scroll to page by `docViewer.setCurrentPage(pageNumber)`

How can I scroll to exact text location by quads.

quads `[ { "x1": 97.27023675000001, "y1": 116.36312251485003, "x2": 145.88205900000003, "y2": 116.36312251485003, "x3": 145.88205900000003, "y3": 68.70635724689998, "x4": 97.27023675000001, "y4": 68.70635724689998 } ]`

Framework: React 16.6.0

PDFTron: 7.0.0

Platform: Windows

Answer (score 1):

For this, you'll need to convert those quads from page coordinates to window coordinates to get the scroll position see this guide https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/coordinates/#converting-between-window-and-viewer-page-coordinates and use scrollTo to scroll

Comment: Thanks Sardor I am finally able to get window coordinates and to scroll the pdf I did some further dig in, as web viewer is embeded in an iframe and cannot be accessible directly https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/customizing-styles/#accessing-dom-directly this helped me out.